# Forcing the for loop to start with the same ligne

Tags: python, postgresql

I want to force the for loop to start always with the same ligne, so that the order of all lignes of the dataset still always the same.
In other words, when I'm searching the index of the ligne with id=15, I found always a diffrent result.

Here is my code:

```
`import psycopg2 as p
conn = p.connect("dbname=Chicago user=postgres password=admin host=localhost ")

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from chicago_2po_4pgr")
nbrows = cur.rowcount
rows = cur.fetchall()
for r in range(0,nbrows):
    id=rows[r][0]
    if id==15:
        print(r,rows[r][0],rows[r][1])`
```

The result of the first run is:

```
`56153 15 4271616`
```

(r is 56153)

The result of the second run (of the same code) is:

```
`126523 15 4271616`
```

(r is 126523)

Any suggestion of how can I edit my code to have always the same order of lignes?

Comment: Your query is unordered, so postgres doesn't guarantee any particular row will be first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add an `ORDER BY` clause. SQL queries without order by can return results in any arbitrary order.
2. If the data being queried can be changed (insert, update or delete) then the record at position 15 can change. You could query a specific key value, or grab the result set and index it by a key, to get a consistent result.